# Subsets $S$ such that $7 \notin S $ or $2 \notin S $

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

> How many subsets $S \subseteq\{1,2...10\}$ are there such that $7 \notin S $ or $2
>  \notin S $?

I can't find the right way to write a formal response. I think that we should consider at least $18$ subsets, deleting once $2$ and once $7$ from the entire set. Then we should consider all the pairs and triples excluding the same two elements and so on. I'm really confused, any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**:

- How many subsets are there containing **neither** $2$ **nor** $7$?
- How many subsets are there containing $2$ and **not** $7$?
- How many subsets are there containing $7$ and **not** $2$?

For the second one, any subset must be a union of $\{2\}$ and any subset of $\{1,3,4,5,6,8,9,10\}$. Can you say something similar for the other two?

Comment: Check the edit, I changed symbol.

Comment: I've corrected the answer

Answer (score 6):

Another possible method:

How many subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ are there in total? Call this number $n$.

How many subsets contain both 2 and 7? This is the same as the number of subsets of $\{1,3,4,5,6,8,9,10\}$. Call this number $m$.

Then your solution is $n - m$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Let $S' = \lbrace 1,3,4,5,6,8,9,10\rbrace$. How many subsets does $S'$ have? Call $n$ that amount.

To any of those subsets, you can add $\lbrace 2\rbrace$ or $\lbrace 7\rbrace$ or neither to have any of the desired subsets. So you have $3n$ subsets of $S$ that don't contain $2$ or $7$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

How many subsets has set $\{1,\dots,10\}$ in total?

How many of these subsets $S$ satisfy $2\in S$ **and** $7\in S$?

So how many do not?